# Row Protection, after input, when sheet is shared with non google users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For the scheduling of tennis matches, we have created a sheet in which 170 duo-participants can fill in their names. This sheet is accessible to everyone (so you do not even have to have a Google account)
However, we are looking for the appropriate script to protect the cells that are filled in against possible changes.

Currently a protect is set up when a cell is edited.
But unfortunately, the protect does not work if it is filled in by a non-logged-in person. The protection is made, but not applied.

Who can help us customize the script, so that once a day (eg midnight) all filled cells are protected by anyone (by trigger)

I have set up a [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MkNMDSYhsmiJmcchN4DB5F5d1LuBQv5EH07mrBgDDkY/edit#gid=0) that is accessible to those who can help.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PLANNING");
    var Range = Sheet.getActiveRange();
    var Row = Range.getRowIndex();

    var Reeks = Sheet.getRange("D"+ Row);

    if (Reeks.getValue() != "") {

        if (Reeks.getValue() != "FOUT") {

            Range.setNote('geboekt op: ' + new Date());

            var LockRange = Sheet.getRange(Row, 6, 1, 2);

            var protection = LockRange.protect().setDescription('Row ' + Row + ' Protected');

            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a simple trigger use an installable trigger.

1. Change the name of your function name `onEdit` to something else like `protectOnEdit`
2. Add the installable trigger to run `protectOnEdit` (or whatever you named your function)

The above because simple trigger function can't execute methods that require authorization like `removeEditors`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find the reason why the script does not work. Setting up a trigger does not seem to work anyway.
I think it has to do with the other protections that arise. The sheet was originally protected with the EXCEPTION of a specific range. If the script wants to secure a row in that specific range, both statements go against each other.

I will try to figure it out further in the coming days